# How to have onClick() on XML nodes

Tags: c#, listview

Is it possible to applying some sort of "onClick" event on the XML nodes? With the following:

```
<tables>
<test>
<code>123</code>
</test>
</tables>
```

If I read the XML file into my project and display it in a `ListView`, can I add an "on click" method to 123?

Comment: Where are you displaying the XML? Are you parsing it nicely or just displaying it in a text box?

Comment: Im displaying the xml nodes in a ListView box ... listView1.Items.Add(textReader.Value);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have OnClick event for each item on a ListView, go to ListView -> Properties and set Activation to OneClick.

After, you have to write your code inside a ListView Item Activate Event :

```
private void listView1_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
 //Your code
}
```

Comment: This answers half of the question because if i do this it applys to every single node added to the actual ListView Thanx Regardless

Comment: Why don't you check which selectedItem is on inside ItemActivate method?